# How to mock Grails' dynamic controller methods in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails

In my Grails application, I use a custom link generator that dynamically adds the current tenant's name as parameter to all links. In my unit tests, I now get a `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException` in my unit tests when it calls redirect(), because it's obviously missing the required, dynamic parameter.

I tried adding a custom redirect method to the controllers metaclass, but it's not picked up correctly:

```
MyController.metaClass.redirect = { Map params ->
}
```

Is there any way I can intercept the dynamic controller methods or set a mock link generator to add the parameter?

Comment: I was able to work around it using integration tests instead, but it would still be nice to have a solution for future reference.

Comment: The question lucks clarity! Please add more description to it! Add where the link is generated and how it used! This is a black boxed question!